# How to elaborate 2 type of Accelerometer data

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

(Sorry for My bad English, I'm Italian) 
I'm new in Android Programming and I have this problem:
I need the Accelerometer data (max and min value of the sqrt(x*x..)) every "1" seconds and if the absolute value of their difference (the delta) is < of 0.4*Gravity_earth, i need the data that i acquired in the previous 5 seconds of the condition, then i calculate the max value. If the value is > of THRESHOLD i flag a "non-fall" or a "fall". 
Can someone solve simply this My problem? 
Thank you! 
this is my solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{


SensorManager sm;
float acc;  
private float [] sensorData;
float azimuth,pitch,roll;
float omegaMagnitude;
//ArrayList
ArrayList<Float> tutteLeAcc =new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Float> previousAcc=new ArrayList();
Iterator<Float> it;
Iterator<Float> it1;
float accMax;
float accMin;

float accPreviousMax;
float deltaAcc;


   private static final String TAG = "SIMTHR";

   public static final int MSG_C = 3; 
   public static final int MSG_D = 4; 


   WorkerThread mWorkerThread;
   WorkerThread1 mWorkerThread1;

   boolean isRunning = false;
   boolean running;
   Button btnStart,btnStop;
   TextView txtLog;
   int tt = 0;

   boolean caduta;



   final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         switch (msg.what) {

         case MSG_C:
            //it=tutteLeAcc.iterator();
            txtLog.setText("");
            txtLog.append("\nAmax: "+Float.toString(accMax)+" Amin:         "+Float.toString(accMin)+" dA: "+Float.toString(deltaAcc));
            tutteLeAcc.clear();

            break;

         case MSG_D:

             txtLog.append("\nPreviousACCmax: "+Float.toString(accPreviousMax)+"\n");
             //previousAcc.clear();

         break;
         }
         caduta=Detection(previousAcc,deltaAcc);
         //previousAcc.clear();
      }
   };


    class WorkerThread extends Thread {

      public Handler mCallerHandler;
      private int nn = 1;

      public WorkerThread(Handler handler) {

       mCallerHandler = handler;
        Log.i(TAG,"create WorkerThread");
      }

  public void run() {
     nn = 0;
     while(running){
     try {
        Log.i(TAG,"WorkerThread inizia qua");
        if (mCallerHandler!=null) {


           accMax=trovaMax(tutteLeAcc);
           accMin=trovaMin(tutteLeAcc);
           deltaAcc=Math.abs(accMax-accMin);
           Thread.sleep(1000);  
           mCallerHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_C).sendToTarget();

           Log.i(TAG,"WorkerThread finisce qua");
        }
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"errore in WorkerThread "+e.toString());
     }
  }
  }


  public synchronized void start() {
     running=true;
     super.start();
     Log.i(TAG,"WorkerThread avviato");
  }

  public synchronized void cancel() {
      running=false;
      Log.i(TAG,"WorkerThread avviato");
   }
```

}

```
     class WorkerThread1 extends Thread {

      public Handler mCallerHandler;
      private int nn = 1;

      public WorkerThread1(Handler handler) {
         // salvo l'handler dei messaggi dell'activity chiamante
         mCallerHandler = handler;
         Log.i(TAG,"create WorkerThread1");
      }

      public void run() {

         nn = 0;
         while(running){
         try {
            Log.i(TAG,"WorkerThread1 inizia qua");
            if (mCallerHandler!=null) {

               accPreviousMax=trovaMax(previousAcc);
               Thread.sleep(5000);  
               mCallerHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_D).sendToTarget();

               Log.i(TAG,"WorkerThread finisce qua");
            }
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"errore in WorkerThread "+e.toString());
         }
      }
      }

      // avvio del thread
      public synchronized void start() {
         running=true;
         super.start();
         Log.i(TAG,"WorkerThread avviato");
      }

      public synchronized void cancel() {
          running=false;
          Log.i(TAG,"WorkerThread avviato");
       }

   }


        @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
          Log.i(TAG,"Activity ONCREATE");

  sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

  sm.registerListener(this,sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  sm.registerListener(this, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  sm.registerListener(this, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

  // oggetti della User Interface
  btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
  btnStop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
  txtLog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLog);
  txtLog.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

  sensorData = new float[9];

  // button per l'avvio del thread
  btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          if (mWorkerThread!=null&&mWorkerThread1!=null) {
             mWorkerThread.cancel();
             mWorkerThread1.cancel();
             mWorkerThread = null; mWorkerThread1 = null;
             txtLog.append("\nrichiesto arresto THREAD 1 e 2 #"+Integer.toString(tt)+"\n");
          }
          tt++;
          mWorkerThread = new WorkerThread(mHandler);
          mWorkerThread1 = new WorkerThread1(mHandler);
          mWorkerThread.start(); mWorkerThread1.start();
          isRunning = true;
          txtLog.append("\nrichiesto avvio THREAD 1 e 2\n");
       }
    });

    // button per l'arresto del thread
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          if (mWorkerThread!=null&&mWorkerThread1!=null) {
             mWorkerThread.cancel();
             mWorkerThread1.cancel();
             mWorkerThread = null; mWorkerThread1 = null;
             txtLog.append("\nrichiesto arresto THREAD 1 e 2\n");
          }
          isRunning = false;
       }
    });
```

}

```
      public void Deregistra(){
sm.unregisterListener(this);
       }


         public void Registra(){
sm.registerListener(this,sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
           }

           @Override
           public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

float [] values = event.values;


synchronized (this) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

                sensorData[0] = event.values[0];

                sensorData[1] = event.values[1];

                sensorData[2] = event.values[2];


            if ((sensorData[3] != 0)||(sensorData[4] != 0)||(sensorData[5] != 0)
                    ||(sensorData[6] != 0)||(sensorData[7] != 0)||(sensorData[8] != 0))

            {

                     float ax=sensorData[0];
                     float ay=sensorData[1];
                     float az=sensorData[2];



                     acc=(float) Math.sqrt((ax*ax)+(ay*ay)+(az*az));

                     /*
                     tutteLeAcc.add(acc);
                     accMax=trovaMax(tutteLeAcc);
                     accMin=trovaMin(tutteLeAcc);
                     deltaAcc=Math.abs(accMax-accMin);
                       */
                     tutteLeAcc.add(acc);
                     previousAcc.add(acc);

                    }

            }


        else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION ) {


            sensorData [3] = values[0];
            sensorData [4] = values[1];
            sensorData [5] = values[2];


            if ((sensorData[0] != 0)||(sensorData[1] != 0)||(sensorData[2] != 0)
                    ||(sensorData[6] != 0)||(sensorData[7] != 0)||(sensorData[8] != 0))
            {
                    azimuth=sensorData[3];
                    pitch=sensorData[4];
                    roll=sensorData[5];


            }
        }
        else if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){
            sensorData [6] = values[0];
            sensorData [7] = values[1];
            sensorData [8] = values[2];

            final float gx=sensorData[6];
            final float gy=sensorData[7];
            final float gz=sensorData[8];

            if ((sensorData[0] != 0)||(sensorData[1] != 0)||(sensorData[2] != 0)
                    ||(sensorData[3] != 0)||(sensorData[4] != 0)||(sensorData[5] != 0))
            {

                float axisX = sensorData[6];
                float axisY = sensorData[7];
                float axisZ = sensorData[8];

                // Calculate the angular speed of the sample
                omegaMagnitude = (float) Math.sqrt((axisX*axisX) + (axisY*axisY) + (axisZ*axisZ));


            }
        }

}
```

}

```
            public float trovaMin(ArrayList<Float> a){
Iterator<Float> it=a.iterator();
float min=a.get(0);
while(it.hasNext()){
    Float x=it.next();
    if(x<min){
        min=x;}
}
return min;
```

}

```
         public float trovaMax(ArrayList<Float> a){
Iterator<Float> it=a.iterator();
float max=a.get(0);
while(it.hasNext()){
    Float x=it.next();
    if(x>max){
        max=x;}
}
return max;
```

}

```
          public boolean Detection(ArrayList<Float> accPrec,float delta){
boolean intentional=true, static=true, lying=false;
float am;


if(delta<0.4*SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH){
   statico=true;
    Log.v("STATIC?", "yes");

    if(static){
       if(Math.abs(pitch)>=140||Math.abs(pitch)<30){ 
       lying=true;
       Log.v("LYING?", "yes");
       if(allungato){
          am=findMax(accPrec); 
          if(am>2.5*SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH||omegaMagnitude>200){
              intentional=true;
              Log.v("INTENTIONAL?", "yes");
          }else{
              intenzionale=false;
              Log.v("INTENTIONAL?", "no");
          }
       }
       }else {
           lying=false;
           Log.v("STANDING?", "yes");
           }
       }
       } else {
           static=false;
           Log.v("STATIC?", "no");
           }

      if(static&&lying&&!intenional)
          return true;

      else return false;
      }
```

}

Comment: Most likely you need timer. For more help show something you tried.

Comment: I have edit my post now.. Please help me, i'm confused  :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact way of telling which samples are got which second. but you can approximate it by fixing frequency at which you get accelerometer updates.

Lets say we request 50 samples for second (50 hz)

for this

```
sm.registerListener(this,sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),50000000);
```

Dont use android sensor delay constants(i.e SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) they are different for different vendor devices.

Now just run a simple counter 0 to 50 (no other way :()

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

my advice is to run the sensor at the maximum possible frequency:
sm.registerListener(this,sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
because, any way, the rate indicated with a number is not strictly observed by the device in any case; besidesm that "numeric" rate is supported only since API v.2.3.
Then, you should write the onSensorChanged method like that.
Comment: you check if the current time is more than the latestSensorChange + DELTASENSOR (that is the number of milliseconds you want to wait between to Sensor values).

```
 @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float[] values = event.values;
    long Now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (Now > (latestSensorChange + DELTASENSOR)) {

/*            if ((mDbHelper.getOldVal(BreathDbAdapter.IDX_X) != values[BreathDbAdapter.IDX_X]) ||
                    (mDbHelper.getOldVal(BreathDbAdapter.IDX_Y)!= values[BreathDbAdapter.IDX_Y]) ||
                    (mDbHelper.getOldVal(BreathDbAdapter.IDX_Z)!= values[BreathDbAdapter.IDX_Z])) {

  */
        msg = "Accelerometer: " + values[0]
                + ", " + values[1] + ", " + values[2] + " at " + Now + " (EndTime =" + EndTime +")";
        mTextViewAccelerometer.setText(msg);
        Log.v(TAG, msg );
        latestSensorChange = Now;
        if (Now > EndTime) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Fine del Test at " + Now);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Please, let me know if it helps (sennò ti vengo a cercare perchè sono Italiano anch'io :-) )
Checco